# string invalid for xpath when trying to scrape text from span using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to use an XPATH I have extracted from a website to try and take th einner text for a span tag but then string is showing errors in visual studio.

The xpath copied from chrome is

```
//*[@id="tracking-wrapper"]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/h3/span

string orderstatus = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id="tracking - wrapper"]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/h3/span")[0].InnerText;
```

Comment: You need to escape those double-quotes inside the string: `"//*[@id=\"tracking - wrapper\"]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/h3/span"`.

Comment: brilliant, that has fixed it for me. thank you.